# codeIgniter Index.php Removal from URL

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, uri

I know this question has been asked one thousand time. But I have problem applying it to my project however.

**What I do:** I have copied the following code (suggested by CI Docs) in .htaccess file in my application folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**PROBLEM:** it does not work and it throws 404 or Internal Error. I also have tries creating new .htaccess file in my root folder, or copying the above code in system folder's .ht . none of them works. 404 or internal error are inervitable

Answer (score 3):

paste the following code in your htaccess file inthe root folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

and the in the config.php file change the line with

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: where you have copied this code? in root folder or in application folder?

Comment: if you copied the code in your root .htaccess file then put "Deny from all" in the .htaccess file inside application folder.

Comment: it still throws 500 Internal Error

Comment: I have set both system's and applications .ht to "Deny from all". also removed index.php as the base Index file.

Comment: can you provide me your url?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in **config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. it is done. The problem was that I had not activated the APACHE rewire_module

Sorry if I wasted your time.

thanks